# Rutas de API no encontradas en Debian 10

Tags: api, laravel-8, debian, routes

Estoy creando una serie de API's en Laravel 10 para una aplicación; las mismas funcionan perfectamente bién en el equipo de desarrollo, que es un equipo con Windows 10 con php 8.1; cuando ejecuto en el Visual Studio Code php artisan serve y pruebo los endpoints con Postman, funcionan perfectamente; necesito hacer el deploy de estas APIs en un servidor con Apache y Debian 10, el cual también tiene php 8.1; sin embargo, al hacer el deploy y tratar de testear los endpoints con Postman, siempre me devuelve un error 404; el servidor está bien, ya que tengo, por ejemplo, una página de wordpress funcionando perfectamente bien allí; de hecho, cuando coloco en el buscador https://direccion-servidor/carpeta-apis/, me muestra el contenido de la raíz de la carpeta carpeta-apis, que es donde está el código de las APIs; sin embargo, al tratar de acceder a alguna de las mismas, por ejemplo https://direccion-servidor/carpeta-apis/api/ejemplo1, me devuelve el error 404, pero al testear http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ejemplo1 (en local) funciona si problema; el contenido de routes/api.php es:

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "api" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/
Route::post('/register', [App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'register']);
Route::get('/api/verify-email/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'verify'])->name('verification.verify');
Route::get('/api/prueba1', [App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'prueba1'])->name('prueba1');
Route::get('/prueba2', [App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'prueba2'])->name('prueba2');
Route::post('/resend-verification', [App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'resendVerify']);
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/password/reset', [App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth\ResetPasswordController::class,'resetPassword'])->name('password.reset');
Route::post('/password_update', [App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth\ResetPasswordController::class, 'password_update'])->name('password.update');
Route::post('/login',[App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth\AuthController::class,'login']);

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum','verified'])->group(function () {
//     Route::post('/pueblos_indigenas',[PueblosIndigenasController::class,'store']);
//     Route::put('/pueblos_indigenas/{id}',[PueblosIndigenasController::class,'update']);
//     Route::delete('/pueblos_indigenas/{id}',[PueblosIndigenasController::class,'destroy']);
    Route::post('/logout',[App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth\AuthController::class,'logout']);
});
```

Alguién tendrá alguna idea de por qué funcionan en windows en local y no en el servidor de debian?

Comment: Revisa tu servidor acepte conexiones tcp entrantes al puerto 8000, y posiblemente las salientes también al mismo puerto.

Comment: El puerto 8000 lo usa es el servidor interno de laravel, el cuál no se usa en el servidor de debian